# Converting struct to uint64 causes custom OS to crash

Tags: c, struct, operating-system, endianness, uint64

I'm currently making my own OS. I've successfully created an IDT, and I wanted to improve performance, so I thought using `uint64_t`s and bit shifting would help me. The whole file is a bit too large to show here, so I'm going to show only the snippets necessary.

```
#define NO_STRUCT
#ifndef NO_STRUCT
  struct idtEntry{
  uint16_t baseLow;
  uint16_t segSel;
  uint8_t alwaysZero;
  uint8_t flags;
  uint16_t base_high;
  }__attribute__((packed));

  typedef struct idtEntry idtEntry_t;

#else

typedef uint64_t idtEntry_t;
#endif
```

---

```
void idtSetEntry(int entryNo, uint32_t base, uint16_t segSel, uint8_t flags){
#ifndef NO_STRUCT
    idtEntries[entryNo].baseLow = base & ~(0xffff << 16);
    idtEntries[entryNo].segSel = segSel;
    idtEntries[entryNo].flags = flags;
    idtEntries[entryNo].base_high = base >> 16;
    idtEntries[entryNo].alwaysZero = 0;
#else
  idtEntries[entryNo] = ((uint64_t)base & 0xFFFF) | ((uint64_t)segSel << 16) | ((uint64_t)flags << 40) | (((uint64_t)base & 0xFFFF0000) << 32);
#endif

}
```

Oh yeah, btw, I'm using linux and the i386 gcc elf compiler (5.3.2).
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, considering the fact that the x86 platform is little endian, I've flipped the elements in the int, and it works great in the test program, but this code causes grub to miss the multiboot header. Any explanations??

EDIT:

So, replacing the uint64_t with a uint32_t[2] fixes it, does anybody have any idea why? Is it because I'm using a 64 bit variable on a 32 bit machine? (I seriously doubt that since other versions of GCC (AVR, ARM) "assemble" bigger variables..)

Comment: `44` --> `32`, but you might want to check the assembly code that the compiler generates. I expect that the structure code is actually faster than your bit twiddling code.

Comment: @user3386109 still gives the same error, but damn was I stupid to haven't noticed it

Comment: Create an entry using the structure, and print out the 8 bytes. Then create the same entry using your solution, print the bytes, and compare.

Comment: Or just use the same scheme universally.  Don't try to use idtEntry-as-uint64_t interchangeably with idtEntry-as-struct.  Write the appropriate bit-twiddling macros for packing and unpacking the internal fields, and use them everywhere.

Comment: I think `(itdEntry) { 0x0102, 0x0304, 0x05, 0x06, 0x0708 }` would be `(uint64_t) 0x0708060503040102` in little-endian.

Comment: @user3386109 it works that way, but it doesn't work this way, for some reason I can't fathom

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's my plan, but only if this works properly, which it obviously doesn't (also, having the structs around  as a reference for bit shifting is useful)

Comment: a 64 bit entry does not automatically contain zeros for any bits not explicitly set.   So the unassigned bits could contain any trash.

Comment: why make things more difficult for your self?   with the struct, you can reference fields and don't care about bit/byte ordering.  With the 64bit that becomes a problem.  To help ease your work load, make a union of the 64bit and the struct.

Comment: @user3629249 As I've mentioned before, I'm planning on removing structs from my code entirely, and use ints only. But before I do that, I need to make sure that the code works, but it doesn't (the uint64_t version atleast). I've already tried setting the alwaysZero bits to 0, didn't make a difference...